# Angular 2/4 How to style angular material design snackbar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am new to Angular2/4 and angular typescript. I want to style the angular material design **snackbar**  for example change the background color from black and font color to something else.
How do i go about styling the "snackbar"  ?

I have the material design snackbar in the service/core and to make it available i call it in every component as needed.

How can I style the Angular 2 material design "snackbar"in Angular 2/4? I have included the code snippet below:

**service/core**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { DOCUMENT } from'@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MdDialogConfig, ComponentType } from '@angular/material'; 
import {MdSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

constructor(
    public dialog: MdDialog,
    public snackBar: MdSnackBar,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) public doc: any   ) {
      dialog.afterOpen.subscribe((ref: MdDialogRef<any>) => {
        if (!doc.body.classList.contains('no-scroll')) {
        doc.body.classList.add('no-scroll');
        }
      });
      dialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe(() => {
        doc.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
      });        }

   openSnackBar(message: string, action?: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 4000,
    });   }
```

**wiz.components.ts**
....

```
 saveData(): void {
    this.advisorClientModel.currentStep = this.currentStep;
    this.advisorClientModel.clientId = this.faService.getClientId();
    this.advisorClientModel.isMaxAmount = this.isMaximumAmount;
    this.advisorClientModel.desiredLoanAmount = this.loanAmount;
    this.advisorClientModel.maxLoanAmount = this.eligibleSelected.advanceAmount;
    this.advisorClientModel.pledgedAccounts = this.getPledgedAccountsArray();
    this.advisorClientModel.pledgedMarketValue = this.getPledgedMarkeValue();

    this.faService.updateAdvisorClient( this.advisorClientModel )
      .subscribe(
        successModel => {
          this.coreService.openSnackBar("Your Data Has been Saved");
          this.navigateTo("fa/wiz" + (this.currentStep + 1));
        },
        error => {
          this.onError(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`md-snackbar` provides a service to provide custom `config`. One the properties of `config` is `extraClasses` that allows to add CSS classes to the snack bar container ([doc](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api)).

`extraClasses` can be used with `::ng-deep` to override the default CSS classes. Here's an example:

**component.ts:**

Requires following `import` in the component:

```
import {MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarConfig} from '@angular/material';
```

(providing custom configuration)

```
openSnackBar(message: string, action?: string) {
  let config = new MdSnackBarConfig();
  config.extraClasses = ['custom-class'];
  this.snackBar.open(message, action ? 'Action Label' : undefined, config);
}
```

**component.css:**

```
::ng-deep snack-bar-container.custom-class {
  background: yellow;
}

::ng-deep .custom-class .mat-simple-snackbar {
  color: green;
}
```

Here's a [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/z5ky5iAUClpUUikgz7WX?p=preview) if you would like to try.

**NOV 2018 UPDATE: Angular 6+**

The syntax has changed a bit, with the `md-` prefix being replaced `mat-` and `extraClasses` was replaced with `panelClass`.  The function is overall the same though:

```
const config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
config.panelClass = ['custom-class'];
...
```

and the imports too:

```
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sidenote: All this "Md..." stuff got renamed to "Mat...". For instance `MatSnachBarConfig`.

Comment: `extraClasses` is now deprecated. Use `panelClass` instead.

Comment: Also, if you need to change color of the action button, try this `::ng-deep .custom-class .mat-simple-snackbar-action {
  color: green;
}`

Comment: What if  Snackbar is inside a service? How do I call styles from a service?

Answer (score 16):

I made the following code to work with Angular 6 and Angular Material 6.

The service that contain the snackBar calls:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
   constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

   showError(message: string) {
      const config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
      config.panelClass = ['background-red'];
      config.duration = 5000;
      this.snackBar.open(message, null, config);
   }
}
```

Add the css class in the **styles.css** file:

```
.background-red{
   background-color: rgb(153, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: It is only a control variable. It's necessary to not open two progress, but this is not in this snippet, you can ignore it. I will remove it from the snippet.

Comment: I thought so. That's why I asked, so you could remove. And there's also a missing ";" after the config.duration line.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I fixed it.

Comment: I had to use a class .mat-snack-bar-container.background-red, otherwise the .background-red class get's overwritten.

Comment: I added `!important` to everything in `styles.css` to get it to work

Answer (score 8):

From mat `SnackBarConfig Class` you can add

`panelClass: string | string[]`

"Extra CSS classes to be added to the snack bar container".

```
this.snackBar.open("Your custom Message", '', {
      panelClass:"custom_sneak_bar"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Angular 5 and above you dont need to use custom config service just pass extraClasses array after duration on method openFromComponent.

**Here's how**

**app.module.ts**:

```
  import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Add to import

```
@NgModule({ declarations: [ .. ], imports: [ MatSnackBarModule ]....
```

**component.ts**:

Requires following import in the component:

```
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
```

Example method that calls SnackBar

```
openSnackBar(message, type) {
   let extraClasses;
   if (type == 'error') {
     extraClasses = ['background-red'];
   } else {
     extraClasses = ['background-green'];
 }

 this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackBarTemplateComponent, {
   duration: 30000,
   extraClasses: extraClasses,
   data: {
     message: message,
     type:type
   }
 });
}
```

Add respective classes to global style.css
style.css:

```
.background-red{
  background-color: rgb(153, 50, 50);
}
.background-green{
  background-color: rgb(29, 102, 29);
}
```

Comment: I had to add !important to the style. Works!

Answer (score 2):

For angular 6 to 9 works with (In your global scss style for material)

Explaination: Customize your snackBar with an @mixin function, in this case is called "@mixin snack-theme($theme)", then you add all classes declared in this function to your templace like this

`@include snack-theme($my-app-theme);`

Global scss file (styles.scss):

```
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss';
@include mat-core();

$background-primary: #232323;
$background-accent: #353535;
$background-warn: #c1640c;
$font-color-default: silver;

$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-green, 700);
$my-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-cyan, 800 );
$my-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 400);


$my-app-theme: mat-dark-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn);


@mixin snack-theme($theme) {
    // Extract whichever individual palettes you need from the theme.
    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
    $warn: map-get($theme, warn);


    .mat-snack-bar-container {
        background-color: $background-accent !important;
        color: $font-color-default;
    }
    //Added with panelClass property
    .snack-error {
        button {
            color: mat-color($warn)
        }
    }
    //Added with panelClass property
    .snack-success {
        button {
            color: mat-color($primary)
        }
    }
}

@include snack-theme($my-app-theme);

...
```

And calling snack like (In your component)

```
        this.snackBar.open("your message", 
           "your action",
          {
            duration: 3000,
            panelClass: (isSuccess ? ["snack-success"] : ["snack-error"])
          })
```

snack-success and snack-error class are defined in @mixed function (@mixin snack-theme)

NOTE: Doesn't forget to include your global scss file in your scss component.
For example:

[image: Global scss reference in your scss component]

Comment: Please consider adding explanation to your answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the 2023 Angular 16 solution:

TypeScript:

```
this.snackBar.open("Error!", "Close", {
  duration: 10000,
  panelClass: ["red-snackbar"]
});
```

styles.css:

```
.red-snackbar {
  --mdc-snackbar-container-color: red;
  --mat-snack-bar-button-color: black;
  --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: white;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

**::ng-deep** support will be dropped, as announced any time soon. Set **encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None** on your message bar component, and you are good to go:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { MessageBarType } from './message-bar.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-bar',
  templateUrl: 'message-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['message-bar.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MessageBarComponent implements OnInit {

  public MessageBarType: typeof MessageBarType = MessageBarType;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: { text: String, type: MessageBarType }) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Then in your **scss** file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import '~app/theme-defs';

snack-bar-container {
  &.error {
    background-color: mat-color($warn);
  }

  &.warning {
    background-color: mat-color($dark-warn);
  }

  &.info {
    background-color: mat-color($accent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Angular 9 at the moment)
Hi, here is a summary of the two links at the bottom.
You get here the call function with css class and variables passed and the way to get their values in the snackBar component. Hope this helps

In the component where you wish to rise a snackBar, the "father component" :

```js
import {
  MatSnackBar
} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {
  SnackBarComponent
} from '../../../shared/snack-bar/snack-bar.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-father-component',
  templateUrl: './father-.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./father-editor.component.scss'],
})
export class FatherComponent implements OnInit {

  private _durationInSeconds = 5;

  get durationInSeconds(): number {
    return this._durationInSeconds;
  }

  set durationInSeconds(value: number) {
    this._durationInSeconds = value;
  }

  private _className: string;

  get className(): string {
    return this._className;
  }

  set className(value: string) {
    this._className = value;
  }

  private _mMessage: string;

  get mMessage(): string {
    return this._mMessage;
  }

  set mMessage(value: string) {
    this._mMessage = value;
  }

  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // your onInit code
  }

// Calling that function rises the snackBar, from .ts this.openSnackBar()
// From template event <button (click)="openSnackBar()"></button> etc...
// No needs to insert the <app-snack-bar> tag in the template.

  openSnackBar() {
    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackBarComponent, {
      duration: this.durationInSeconds * 1000,
      data: {
        myMessage: this.mMessage,
        antoherVar: 'antoher message'
      },
      // here this.className is a string which value is a Bulma class 'has-text-info', snackbar automatically uses the value from panelClass
      panelClass: this.className
    });
  }
```

Then the component which is the snackBar itSelf, the "child component" :

```js
import {
  Component,
  Inject,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA
} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snack-bar',
  templateUrl: './snack-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snack-bar.component.scss'],
})
export class SnackBarComponent implements OnInit {

  myMessage: string;
  antoherVar: string;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any
  ) {
  // there you get the datas you have passed to the snackbar through the openSnackBar function in the father-component, setting up local properties to their values
    this.myMessage = data.myMessage;
    this.antoherVar = data.antoherVar;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

```html
<!--Here we use the local variable set with the datas passed through the data object -->
<!--No needs to setup a class to use the panelClass value passed, it is automatic -->
<span>{{ myMessage }}</span>
```